# Hiding the virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I wanted to ask a question about Hyper-V.

I have several solutions on Azure, and they completely suited me until yesterday. I needed to deploy cloud desktops, but the software I want to work with, refuses to run on virtual machines (Sorry, This Application Cannot Be Run Under A Virtual Machine). It all comes down to hiding the virtual machine. Azure does not provide access to additional tools. I tried several options, but they turned out to be useless.

Creating a "virtual machine in a virtual machine" is not possible, nested virtualization is not available. It is not possible to try Hyper-visor, since there is no VT-x. Thanks for attention!

Comment: Nope, not possible. SImple like that.Nested virtualization is one of the cases were Hyper-V may fail.

Comment: Have you carefully read my message? I'm not interested in nested virtualization, I need to hide the traces of the virtual machine.

Comment: Well, you also get an error message telling you it does not work. Which means the developer blocked it. Which means not as per our rules here.

Answer (score 1):

Nested virtualisation is possible in Azure, you need to use a v3 or newer VM to do it.

That said, it’s not going to help you here. The application has been designed not to run on VM and so it won’t, regardless of whether that is in Azure or HyperV. You probably also want to check the licence agreement you signed up to which may well state that this is the case.